# Can't create a linked server connection on SQL Server 2014 to Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, linked-server

I am trying to create a linked server in SQL Server 2014.  I am attempting to connect to an Oracle 11g server.  I am using the Oracle in OraClient 11g connection provided by Oracle.  The ODBC connection is set up on the Server and I can test connect, so it works though Windows.

I right click on the Linked Servers in the database and choose Other Data source.  There is no Oracle provider option there.  If I try and force it using the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC drivers, the connection returns an error message that says "An exception occurred while executing a t-sql statement.  Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for Linked server "Server".  OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Server" returned message "[Micrsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source name not found and no default driver specified."  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

It appears I am missing something, a way for the sql server to recognize the connection, but I can't figure out what.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a couple of days  u I found this:

https://nampark.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/installing-64-bit-odac-11-2-to-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-x64-for-replication/

It gives a great walk through of how to install the missing components I need.  The downside to this solution is that it requires the installation to be done via cmd window.  Not something I have much experience with, but this walk through really gave me the details I needed to get it done.  That cleared the error message I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SQL Mag](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/connecting-sql-server-and-oracle-using-linked-servers):

> Before you can create a SQL Server 2008 linked server to Oracle, you
>   need to install the Oracle client software on the SQL Server 2008
>   system. The Oracle client software provides the network libraries that
>   are required to establish connectivity to the Oracle database. In this
>   case, the Oracle 11g database server is already installed and
>   functional. Installing the Oracle client software on the SQL Server
>   system enables it to connect to the existing Oracle server.

The article applies to 2008/11g but the principle should be the same on 2014/11g.

Comment: That helped.  I have the client software, but under Linked Servers Privders, I am missing the OraOLEDB.Oracle connection.  I'm trying to figure out how to get that loaded right now.